# NonNull annotation - Illegal redefinition of parameter (Eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, non-nullable

I am trying to use the Eclipse NonNull annotation, however I cannot understand the behaviour described below. I don't understand what Eclipse is complaining about....

**Compiles/ Eclipse does not complain about anything:**

```
import org.eclipse.jdt.annotation.NonNull;    
public class NonNullStaticInnerClasses {

        public static class NonNull1{
            protected String nonNullString;
            public void setNonNullString(@NonNull String nonNullString){
                this.nonNullString = nonNullString;
            }
        }

        public static class NonNull2 extends NonNullStaticInnerClasses.NonNull1 {
            public void setNonNullString(@NonNull String nonNullString){
                this.nonNullString = nonNullString;
            }
        }
    }
```

**Eclipse complains about "Illegal redefinition of parameter nonNullString, inherited method from NonNull1 does not constrain this parameter" but compiles/runs fine:**

```
import org.eclipse.jdt.annotation.NonNull;

public class NonNull1{
    protected String nonNullString;
    public void setNonNullString(@NonNull String nonNullString){
        this.nonNullString = nonNullString;
    }
}

public class NonNull2 extends NonNull1 {
    public void setNonNullString(@NonNull String nonNullString){
        this.nonNullString = nonNullString;
    }
}
```

[image]

**Environment:** Eclipse 4.4.1 using Jdk8 (Compiler compliance level: 1.8)
[image]

Comment: Which version of eclipse are you using? And what is the jre compliance level set for this project? I've tried this on the latest eclipse with 1.8 and there is no error. Also have you set/modified any preferences related to errors/warnings in the java compiler settings?

Comment: Added some more information about the environment.